# AutoHotkey - limiting the number and type of characters taken from the string

Tags: autohotkey

I have an ahk script for an IRC client which after entering `nick!ident@host` into the text field and pressing F4 decrypts the ident which is the encrypted form of the IP address:

```
F4::
Clipboard =
Send ^a^x
ClipWait, 0
If ErrorLevel
MsgBox, 48, Error, An error occurred while waiting for the clipboard. Aborting.
Else Clipboard := decode(SubStr(Clipboard, -15, -8)) 
Return

decode(str) {
 Static code := " " "
 ( LTrim Join`s
 00 0x 02 03 04 0z 06 01 08 09 0B 0b 0c 0d 0e 0H x0 xx x2 x3 x4 xz x6 x1 x8 x9 xB xb xc xd xe xH 20 2x
 22 23 24 2z 26 21 28 29 2B 2b 2c 2d 2e 2H 30 3x 32 33 34 3z 36 31 38 39 3B 3b 3c 3d 3e 3H 40 4x 42 43
 44 4z 46 41 48 49 4B 4b 4c 4d 4e 4H z0 zx z2 z3 z4 zz z6 z1 z8 z9 zB zb zc zd ze zH 60 6x 62 63 64 6z
 66 61 68 69 6B 6b 6c 6d 6e 6H 10 1x 12 13 14 1z 16 11 18 19 1B 1b 1c 1d 1e 1H 80 8x 82 83 84 8z 86 81
 88 89 8B 8b 8c 8d 8e 8H 90 9x 92 93 94 9z 96 91 98 99 9B 9b 9c 9d 9e 9H B0 Bx B2 B3 B4 Bz B6 B1 B8 B9
 BB Bb Bc Bd Be BH b0 bx b2 b3 b4 bz b6 b1 b8 b9 bB bb bc bd be bH c0 cx c2 c3 c4 cz c6 c1 c8 c9 cB cb
 cc cd ce cH d0 dx d2 d3 d4 dz d6 d1 d8 d9 dB db dc dd de dH e0 ex e2 e3 e4 ez e6 e1 e8 e9 eB eb ec ed
 ee eH H0 Hx H2 H3 H4 Hz H6 H1 H8 H9 HB Hb Hc Hd He HH
 )"
 Loop, % StrLen(str) / 2
  new .= "." Round((Instr(code, " " SubStr(str, 2 * A_Index - 1, 2), True) - 1) / 3)
 Return SubStr(new, 2)
}
```

Decryption is performed according to the following key:

https://pastebin.com/raw/P8cQtH2v

For example, for user data `asdf!~z3040d4B@webchat` will decrypt the ident from `z3040d4B` as `83.4.13.75` and copies this value to the clipboard.

But there are cases when the encoded form of the IP (ident) is longer or shorter than 8 characters or contains characters that aren't in the decryption key. Then it's impossible to decode the IP correctly. So I would like the script to copy the decryption result to the clipboard only if the retrieved string (between `!` and `@`, omitting the `~` sign if present) is 8 characters long and contains the characters contained in the key I entered. Otherwise, the script should clear the clipboard. How to do it?

Comment: What did you try? Sounds like a very easy problem with with e.g. some [`StrLen()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StrLen.htm). Or maybe a simple Regex like [`!~?[A-z\d]{8}@`](https://regex101.com/r/LzZ9Sa/1), that's probably what I'd do.

Comment: @0x464e unfortunately my knowledge of scripting in this language is very little and I just don't know where to put it in the code. I got this script from a friend.

Answer (score 0):

A regex match approach with e.g the regex [`!~?[A-z\d]{8}@`](https://regex101.com/r/LzZ9Sa/1) is surely most convenient:

```
F4::
    Clipboard := ""
    SendInput, ^a^x
    ClipWait, 0
    if (ErrorLevel)
        MsgBox, 48, Error, An error occurred while waiting for the clipboard. Aborting.
    else if (Clipboard ~= "!~?[A-z\d]{8}@")
        Clipboard := decode(SubStr(Clipboard, -15, -8))
    else
        Clipboard := ""
Return

decode(str) 
{
    static code := " " "
    ( LTrim Join`s
    00 0x 02 03 04 0z 06 01 08 09 0B 0b 0c 0d 0e 0H x0 xx x2 x3 x4 xz x6 x1 x8 x9 xB xb xc xd xe xH 20 2x
    22 23 24 2z 26 21 28 29 2B 2b 2c 2d 2e 2H 30 3x 32 33 34 3z 36 31 38 39 3B 3b 3c 3d 3e 3H 40 4x 42 43
    44 4z 46 41 48 49 4B 4b 4c 4d 4e 4H z0 zx z2 z3 z4 zz z6 z1 z8 z9 zB zb zc zd ze zH 60 6x 62 63 64 6z
    66 61 68 69 6B 6b 6c 6d 6e 6H 10 1x 12 13 14 1z 16 11 18 19 1B 1b 1c 1d 1e 1H 80 8x 82 83 84 8z 86 81
    88 89 8B 8b 8c 8d 8e 8H 90 9x 92 93 94 9z 96 91 98 99 9B 9b 9c 9d 9e 9H B0 Bx B2 B3 B4 Bz B6 B1 B8 B9
    BB Bb Bc Bd Be BH b0 bx b2 b3 b4 bz b6 b1 b8 b9 bB bb bc bd be bH c0 cx c2 c3 c4 cz c6 c1 c8 c9 cB cb
    cc cd ce cH d0 dx d2 d3 d4 dz d6 d1 d8 d9 dB db dc dd de dH e0 ex e2 e3 e4 ez e6 e1 e8 e9 eB eb ec ed
    ee eH H0 Hx H2 H3 H4 Hz H6 H1 H8 H9 HB Hb Hc Hd He HH
    )"
    
    Loop, % StrLen(str) / 2
    {
        if (!InStr(code, block := " " SubStr(str, 2 * A_Index - 1, 2), true))
            return ""
        new .= "." Round((InStr(code, block, true) - 1) / 3)
    }
    return SubStr(new, 2)
}
```

`~=`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#regex)</sup> is the `RegExMatch()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm)</sup> shorthand.

Comment: Doesn't work properly. I used the following example: `abcdef!~nxn616o8@webchat` and the following content appeared in the clipboard: `0.0.118.0`. Since the sample string contained letters that were not in the decryption key, that is, `n` and `o`, the clipboard should be empty.

Besides, how do I get rid of the `j` message after pressing F4?

Comment: The clipboard should also be empty if the ident (value between! and @) will be longer or shorter than 8 characters.

Comment: So it doesn't only need to check that it's 8 characters, it needs to check extra stuff?

Comment: As I wrote in the first post, the script should check that the ident is 8 characters long and that it contains the characters specified in the decryption key.  If both conditions aren't met, the script should clear the clipboard.

Comment: Edited the answer.